# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\right)$ Stolz-Cesaro?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to apply Stolz-Cesaro in order to evaluate this sequence as n approaches to $\infty$?

I got to $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)}$$

Comment: I don't think Stolz-Cesaro is needed here:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n + \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n} = \lim\left(1 + \frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n}\right) = 1$$
since $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = O(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: @VIVID Many thanks! Your answer helped.

Comment: I did not post it as an answer since you asked how to apply Stolz-Cesaro specifically.

Comment: I would have ticked your answer, It answered my wrongly put question. (Please do so, if you want to.)

Comment: No need for big guns. Multiply and divide by $k$. Things will follow easily.

Comment: @Milan I undeleted my old answer and indeed there was no need to state the big O order :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Stolz-Cesaro is needed here:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n + \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n} = \lim\left(1 + \color{red}{\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n}}\right) = 1$$
since the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ expression goes to zero (numerator $\to 0$ and denominator $\to \infty$)

Answer (score 0):

Although Stolz-Cesaro is unnecessary as VIVID says, if you were to use Stolz-Cesaro, you can say the following.

By Stolz-Cesaro, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\ln(n+1))-\ln(\ln(n))}{(n+1)-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\ln(n))}n=0.$$

Now, taking exponents of both sides, we obtain:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}=1.$$